# Fcm Notification Not Received After 3 or 4 hours

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have Integrated Fcm Notification in my project when i Installed app in devices it works fine for 3 or 4 hours, after that i'm not able to get any notification. I think it happen only in oreo because its work in my miui nougat device.
-  i want open activity when message is received. here is my android code:

```
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
    Log.d(TAG, "Message " + remoteMessage.getNotification());
    Log.d(TAG, "Message1 " + remoteMessage.getData());

    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(remoteMessage.getData());
    try {
        f_Id = jsonObject.getString("fid");
        Log.d(TAG, "F_ID" + f_Id);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    util = new Util(mContext);
    back_suburllist = new ArrayList<>();

    createNotificationChannel();
    getApiData();
}
public void getApiData(){
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        Intent openActivity = new Intent(mContext, Activity_Transparant.class);
        openActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_EXCLUDE_FROM_RECENTS | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        openActivity.putExtra("listBundleActivity", bundle);
        mContext.startActivity(openActivity);
    } else {
        Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, BackLoadUrlService.class);
        intent.putExtra("listBundleValue", bundle);
        mContext.startService(intent);
    }
private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        String CHANNEL_ID = mContext.getString(R.string.default_notification_channel_id);
        CharSequence name = getString(R.string.channel_name);
        String description = getString(R.string.channel_description);
        int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, name, importance);
        channel.setDescription(description);
        NotificationManager notificationManager = getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
    }
}
```

Comment: in `oreo` version you set NotificationChannel. or paste your code with `createNotificationChannel();`

Comment: i have edited my code with createnotificationChannel()

Comment: Starting the activity when receiving a push notification is *not advisable*. It's generally *bad UX* (just think of pop-up ads). I would suggest taking advantage of `click_action` instead -- opens your specified activity when the notification is clicked.